# Spring MVC and Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-data-rest

I need to create a controller in a Spring MVC application using Spring-Data-Rest 1.0.0.M2 at the same time.
I’ve created the two servlets in web.xml and they work fine when are alone but not when I want to load them together. Can I use the web tiers simultaneously? 
How can I set the configuration correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This link explains how to add Spring-Data-Rest to an existing Spring MVC application: 
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-rest/wiki/Adding-Spring-Data-REST-to-an-existing-Spring-MVC-Application

Comment: Are there any sample projects to write a brand new Spring Data REST implementation??  Starting with absolutely nothing, and wanting a CRUD accessible DB via REST+JSON ??